# What are the difference between these selectors?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I see the following in http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors, but I could not understand it properly. What is it?

```
E + F   an F element immediately preceded by an E element 
E > F   an F element child of an E element
```

Comment: you already have the explanations in your question

Comment: @musefan — Yes, but the question says he doesn't understand those explanations.

Comment: Here is a fiddle so you can understand better : 

http://jsfiddle.net/vtH4U/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The adjacent selector `E + F`:

This selects an `F` element that is **next to** the `E` element, at the same nesting level. For example:

```
    .a + .b { background-color:blue; }

    <div class='a'>.....</div>
    <div class='b'>This will be blue, because it is next to the 'a' element.</div>
```

Note: It is not to be confused with the sibling selector, `E ~ F`. Both apply to elements that are at the same nesting level in the document, but `+` specifically means they must be next to each other, whereas `~` is any sibling element, so for `~` there could be another element between `a` and `b`, and it would still work, but not for `+`.

- The child selector `E > F`:

This selects an `F` element that is **inside** the `E` element, that is, one nesting level deeper. For example:

```
    .c > .d { background-color:red; }

    <div class='c'>
        <div class='d'>This will be red, because it is immediately inside the 'c' element.</div>
    </div>
```

Note: it is not to be confused with the descendent selector, `E F`, which also looks at elements nested inside each other, but it can apply to any level of nesting. So for the `.c .d` there could be more elements nested between `c` and `d`, and it would still work, but not for `.c > .d`.

I hope that clarifies things for you.

Comment: You mean if we apply e+f in <e></e><f></f><f></f>. The first <f></f> element selects.

Comment: @user2253835 - Yes. Exactly. The `+` would not select the second `f` element. (if you wanted to select both, you could use `~` instead)

Answer (score 1):

```
<e></e><f></f>  — an F element immediately preceded by an E element
<e><f></f></e>  — an F element child of an E element
```

Comment: which element selects if e+f applied.

Comment: @user2253835 — The one which has the same (word-for-word) description as the `+` definition from the question!

Comment: I mean if we apply e+f , it selects e or f?

Comment: It selects F. That's why the sentence says "an F element immediately preceded by an E element" and not "An E element that immediately follows an F element".

Comment: thanks I wanted know exactly about that. But my question was down voted. If am unable to understand, is not good to ask question?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
  <span id="A"></span>
</div>
<div id="B"></div>
```

`E + F` matches the `<div>` with id `B`.

`E > F` matches the `<span>` with id `A`.

So the difference is, whether the element `F` is a sibling or a child of element `E`.